# Using Entity Framework to access a remote database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to be able to use EF to access a database on a remote server.  I have the connection string to remote database in app.config.

When I try this:

```
using (var ctx = new PinnReportEntities("name=remoteConnection"))
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I get this:

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
```

The named connection is in the configuration and is valid, so the issue must be with the EntityClient provider.

Is what I want to do even possible and is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: If your start up project is different to the project that has the entity framework model, then you have to create a config file in the same project for this to work.

Comment: How is your connection string defined? And is your EF using a .edmx file or is it code first?  Since you mention app.config, you're not talking about a web app, right?  Is the ef model in a separate assembly?

Comment: Can you post the connection string (less any sensitive bits)